# Does Jboss (5 or 7) provide any application level metrics?

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x, jboss7.x

I am talking out of the box without configuring anything. I would like to be able to get basic stuff like application response time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a tool out of the box without any configuration that you can use that I know of. You can use JON with some basic configuration set up. Other profiles also require some setting up front. But if your organization uses JBoss heavily then JON may be the route you want to take.

You can utilize [JON](http://www.jboss.org/rhq) for monitoring, provisioning, managing upgrades, deploying applications, etc for all JBoss instances in your domain. You can also monitor the server it's running on (CPU spikes, memory usage, disk space, etc). JON 3.0 is out now so I would recommend starting with that. The community forum is located [here](https://community.jboss.org/en/jbosson).

Other options include using [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) or [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) or [DynaTrace](http://www.dynatrace.com/en/) like tools.

Answer (score 2):

There are some basic metrics in the JBoss AS 7.1.0.CR1b and greater web console.

[image: JBoss AS7 Metrics]